# BAPI Function Get list of customer sort by date DESC

Tags: java, abap, jco, bapi, sap-erp

How to sort by any fields (date example)

I want to retrieve a list of customers sorted by a specific fields, using BAPI Functions and JCo.

I am able to retrieve the list of customers perhaps they are not sorted.

```
<BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND>
  <import>
    <MAX_CNT>100</MAX_CNT>
  </import>
  <tables>
    <SELOPT_TAB>
      <row>
        <TABNAME>KNA1</TABNAME>
        <FIELDNAME>NAME1</FIELDNAME>
        <FIELDVALUE>*</FIELDVALUE>
      </row>
    </SELOPT_TAB>
  </tables>
</BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND>
```

Answer (score 5):

when you directly call a standard bapi that doesn't sort, you have to sort yourself in Java.

Or you write your own function module in ABAP that calls the bapi and sorts the table before it returns the table to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps do you know if there's any standard BAPI that allows it ? sort a list of customer ?. Because sorting it in JAVA might not be the best way to go with the amount of customers @Gerd

Comment: I don't see a problem in sorting in Java, but if you have a huge amount of customers then I would implement the list myself as a function module, let the database do the most of the work, and return exactly the fields that I need.

Comment: To be more precise: "implementing myself" means without bapi in this case

Comment: Yes this is what i taught as well. Since there's a lot amount of customers. And also let say i would want to do it via JAVA, when fetching customers ex : (BAPI_CUSTOMER_FIND)  needs to input MAX_CNT therefore there's no way to know the total. Anyways this been said, I'd rather do it from the function in SAP. Thanks mate!